# WHERE clause stored in Mysql Field

Tags: mysql

I'm using `OpenEMM`, and I'd like to edit a second database with a `trigger`.

I'd like to get all users of a target.
I have two tables :

> - user
> - target which contains a field "target_sql", it's the where clause of the SQL request to retrieve all users of the target

For example : a field in `target_sql` :

```
 (  ( lower(cust.EMAIL) = lower('test@gmail.com'))  )
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE target_sql;
```

And

```
DECLARE targetsql TEXT;
SELECT target_sql FROM target WHERE target_id=1 INTO targetsql;
```

Both doesn't work.

Do you have an idea, how can I do that ?

Comment: Not sure if what you sketch is even possible without means of stored procedures. but anyway, it certainly is very bad style, you should not mix contained data and processing code. In other words: storing sql statements as data inside the database and using it to query the same database is an architecture you really should think twice about. What is your motivation to do so?

Comment: I understand it is certainly a very bad style, but I didn't find another way to do so.
I have a final software which gets information in the MySQL database directly and I can't use processing code such as Ruby or Python...

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I suggest you start reading a bit about "stored procedures". They are like functions you declare, but inside your database server. you can call these procedures by means of sql statements and retrieve and process the result they return. This allows you to store your select logic inside the database on the one hand whilst keeping it strictly separate from the payload data you want to handle. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Hi I agree you should read something about stored procedure and also about prepared statement. You can do that [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) Also here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25c10/1) where i create similar problem like yours so you can see how that looks like.. GL

Comment: Thanks it works with prepared statements !
But, I read that we can't call a stored procedure from a trigger...